# Simple Bootloader for DVD booting

Tags: assembly, x86, boot

Is there a simple bootloader, that just loads code from a DVD to RAM and start it?
I need some assembler code or a binary file for this, no big C bootloaders.
It doesn't matter if it loads my code from a file or from a prefined memory address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,There are a load of bootloader use to load simple kernel to memory and execute it.I forgot site url so I can't give you any information about where you can find out it.Search it on Google.Or you can make your own.
As a Sample:

```
BITS 16
Org 0x7c00
Start:
Jmp 0x7e00 ;Your Kernel
hlt
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55 ;Boot Signature
```

Compile:nasm -f bin bootload.asm bootload.bin